# Baby Rudin Ch. 5 Exercise 2: How does differentiability imply continuity at endpoints?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

(Baby Rudin Chapter 5 Exercise 2)

> Suppose $f'(x) > 0$ in ($a, b$). Prove that $f$ is strictly increasing in ($a, b$), and let
> $g$ be its inverse function.
>
> Prove that $g$ is differentiable, and that $g'(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f′(x)}   \; \; \; 
> (a < x < b)$

I attempted the proof as follows:

> Suppose $f'(x)>0$ in $(a, b)$ for some $x \in (a, b)$.  Then, $f$ is continuous on $\color{blue}{[a, b]}$ and by the Mean Value Theorem, $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}>0 \implies f(b)-f(a)>0$ and we have that $f$ is strictly increasing in $(a, b)$. Now, let $g = f^{-1}(x), t\in (a, b)$ such that $t\ne x$ and $\epsilon>0$. Put $\delta = \epsilon |t-a|>0$. Then, if $0< |t-x|< \delta$, then
> \begin{align*}
>         0< |t-x|< \epsilon |t-a| &\implies |f^{-1}(f(t))-f^{-1}(f(x))|< \epsilon |t-a| \\
>         &\implies \left|\frac{f^{-1}(f(t))-f^{-1}(f(x))}{t-x}\right|< \left|\frac{f^{-1}(f(t))-f^{-1}(f(x))}{t-a}\right|< \epsilon \\
>         &\implies \left|\frac{g(f(t))-g(f(x))}{t-x}\right|< \epsilon
>     \end{align*}
> and we have that $g$ is differentiable. Next, put $h(t) = g(f(t)) = f^{-1}(f(t)) = t$. Note that we satisfy the hypothesis of the Theorem on the chain rule of differentiation; by its consequent, we have
> \begin{equation*}
>         g'(f(x)) = \frac{h'(x)}{f'(x)} = \frac{1}{f'(x)}
>     \end{equation*}
> and we are done.

**My question**: On second reading, I realized that it is not correct to say that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and that I could only conclude that $f$ is continuous on $(a, b)$ based on the fact that $f$ is differentiable on $(a, b)$. Is this true? If so, is there a way to prove that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, or do I need to completely overhaul that part of the proof? **Also, is the rest of my proof correct?**

Comment: No, $f$ need not be defined at $a,b$, e.g., $f(x):=\frac{1}{b-x}+\frac1{a-x}$.  Do it on $[a+\varepsilon,b-\varepsilon]$ instead.

Comment: By the way proving $f(a) <f(b) $ does not really mean that $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a, b) $. A function $f$ is strictly increasing on interval $I$ if for any two points $x, y$ in $I$ with $x<y$ we have $f(x) <f(y) $.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson does my answer answer your question ?

Answer (score 1):

To prove $f’(x)>0$ on $(a,b)$ $ \implies$ $f(x)$ monotonic on $(a,b)$
The argument to is to prove $f(x_{i})<f(x_{j})$ for every $x_{i},x_{j}$ in the interval $(a,b)$ For this can you take the interval $[x_{i},x_{j}]$ and then apply the Mean-value Theorem to get  the inequality.  Hence you do not need continuity on $[a,b]$ but just on $(a,b)$.

---

For the second theorem.
The derivative of $g$ at $y_{0}$ is $$\lim_{y\to y_{0}}{g(y)-g(y_{0})\over y-y_{0}}$$ [Where $y_{0}$ = $f(x_{0})$ The reason for this is $g$ takes inputs that are outputs of $f$ .
 $x_{0}$ is a point in the interval(domain of $f$)].
 The derivative is equal to $$\lim_{y\to y_{0}}\dfrac{1}{ \dfrac{f(g(y))-f(g(y_{0}))}{g(y)-g(y_{0})}}$$ (the denominators  can’t be zero since $f$ and $g$ are one to one  functions) since $f(g(y))=y$. 
 The denominator is equal to $f(x)-f(x_{0})\over x-x_{0}$ and hence 
 The limit of the denominator  is $f’(x)$ (Since $y\to y_{0} \implies x\to x_{0}$ as g is continuous(inverse of monotonic continuous function is continuous ) ) hence $g’$=$1/f’(x_{0})$ by reciprocal law of limits .
Hence the limit exists and the value is computed.

Comment: Why is there a downvote to a reasonably good answer? If there is something which looks confusing one should comment for more explanation rather than downvote. +1 to compensate.

Comment: Thanks, that resolves the 'continuity' part of my question.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson in the epsilon delta proof is not the second implies  always equal to one ? so if you pick epsilon <1 then it won’t be true ?

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson  the definition of the derivative at $g(f(x_0))$  for any $x_0$ the interval is incorrect. in the proof in my answer there is the correct definition . y= $f(x_{0})$ in the proof hence according to my proof $g’(y)=1/f’(x)$  for all $x_0$ in the inerval the derivative is evaluated at $g(f(x_0))$ to get $1/f’(x_0)$