Does differentiability imply continuity at endpoints?

Let $f:[0,4]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable
function. Further let $f(0)=1, f(2)=2$ and $f(4)=3$ then (IIT JAM MS 2006)

A. $\nexists x_1 \in (0,2)$ such that $f'(x)=0.5$
B. $\exists x_1 \in (0,2)$ and $x_2 \in (2,4)$ such that $f'(x_1)=f'(x_2)$
C. $f''(x)<0 \forall x\in (0,4)$
D. $f''(x)>0 \forall x\in (0,4)$


Option B is correct (matching the answer key) from:
By LMVT (Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem) on $[0,2]$, $\exists \alpha \in (0,2)$ such that
$$f'(\alpha) = \frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2-0}=0.5$$
By LMVT on $[2,4]$, $\exists \beta \in (2,4)$ such that
$$f'(\beta) = \frac{f(4)-f(2)}{4-2}=0.5$$
My issue is with the conditions of LMVT (specifically continuity over a closed interval).
Does differentiable in the question mean differentiable over the entire interval? (In which case I can then assume continuity.)
And isn't there an issue where a function cannot be differentiated at the endpoints of a closed interval?

Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755449/baby-rudin-ch-5-exercise-2-how-does-differentiability-imply-continuity-at-endp

Consider $g(x)=\sqrt{4x-x^2}$ when $x \in [0,4]$ as a semicircle, and $h(x)=x$ when $x \in [0,4]$ as a straight line segment.  I would say $g(x)$ was not differentiable at its end points while $h(x)$ was differentiable at its end points.

@Henry can you explain why $h$ is differentiable but $g$ is not.

Even if you used a 1-sided derivative, what value would it have at $x = 0$? Doing it in my head, I get $\frac{2}{0}$, but I might be missing something. What do YOU get?

@Starlight: If you have $z \to 0$ while $z \in [0,4]\backslash {0}$ then $g(z) \to g(0)$ and $h(z) \to h(0)$ so both are continuous, but  $\lim\frac {g(z)-g(0)}{z-0}$ does not exist as a real number while  $\lim \frac{h(z)-h(0)}{z-0}=1$. So I would say there is no $g'(0)$ while there is $h'(0)$.

The condition is satisfied because differentiability implies continuity.
In fact, differentiability on a closed interval is different from that on an open interval. The only difference on a closed interval is that it requires only one-sided derivatives at the endpoints, and can only be one-sided derivatives. Another case is differentiability on a larger open interval, which naturally includes differentiability at the endpoints. This case is usually specified explicitly.
This situation does not exist, because what we require at the endpoints of a closed interval is generally one-sided differentiability.

special:
A function is infinitely differentiable on [a, ∞). Then, at the endpoint a, it can only be infinitely differentiable from the right (one-sided).
I have only addressed one case regarding the meaning of differentiability. For other cases, as mentioned above, specific clarification will be provided
